# SUPPOSE versus IF

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the difference between
**suppose** .  .  ., **then** .  .  .
and
**if** .  .  ., **then** .  .  .
?

For instance, in this...
"Let P(n) be a statement that is defined for all nEZ and let a be a fixed integer.
**Suppose that** both of the following statements are true:

1. P(a) is true
2. for every integer, k ≥ a, if p(k) is true then p(k+1) is true.

Then the statement: "for all integers n ≥ a, p(n)" is true."

Why is it **suppose that** as opposed to **if**

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

As single sentences, "Suppose X, then Y" and "If X, then Y" are synonymous.

We say "Suppose X." when we want to keep X around as an assumption for the next while. This might just be because we have a statement of a theorem that's too long to fit into a single sentence. That's all that is going on in your example.

In *proofs*, we might prove an implication of the form "If X, then Y" by saying "Suppose X", continuing with several steps which are free to use X as an assumption, and concluding Y.

Comment: Yes, exactly. "If.., then.." can only be used in a single sentence, whereas "Suppose/assume that...;then..." can be used either in a single sentence or across sentences, in which case the semicolon becomes a period.