# How to write the proof for $\forall x \in D \, (A(x) \to B(x))$ in standard English.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology

> Question: How to write the proof for $\forall x \in D \, (A(x) \to B(x))$ in standard English.

I recently started reading a book that begins with a short introduction to induction. Although I have a lot of experience writing proofs using induction, I mainly write these proofs in another language. Therefore, I am slightly confused with the specific word choice in English. When trying to phrase for a proof that shows $\forall n \geq a(n \in S \to n + 1 \in S)$, I wrote the following:

Suppose n belongs to S for all $n \geq a$,

... ...

then n+1 also belongs to S.

I'm afraid the beginning of the proof sounds like a complete statement stating that $\forall n \geq a(n \in S)$, which is clearly not what I intended.

I have thought about some alternatives: the book states that wherever some integer $n \geq a$ belongs to S, then n+1 also belongs to S. However, I am unsure about the usage of "some" as it often implies existence. Alternatively, I was thinking about writing suppose n belongs to S where $n \geq a$, then we want to show n+1 is also in S, and the proof continues. However, I felt that this doesn't clearly identify that the statement holds for all n. Additionally, I'm less inclined to write the phrase "we want to show".

So what word choice should I adopt to write this proof? In general, how should I translate the above formula written with logic symbols to standard English?

Comment: “Suppose that for every $n\ge a$, if $n\in S$ then  $n+1 \in S$.“ More generally, for the schema in the title of your question, “Every $D$ that’s an $A$ is (also) a $B$.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > $\forall n{\geq}a\;(n \in S \to n + 1 \in S)\tag1$
>
> - Suppose $n$ belongs to $S$ where $n \geq a$, then we want to show $n+1$ is also in $S.$

This is pretty okay (though I'd [replace “where” with “and”](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4266064/21813)), as it suggests the equivalent statement $$\forall n\;(n \in S\;\text{and}\;n\geq a\;\implies\;n + 1 \in S).\tag2$$ In fact, noting that all three statements $$\forall n{\in}S\;(n\geq a\;\implies\;n + 1 \in S)\tag3$$ are equivalent to one another, here are some alternatives (and more at [‘Any’ versus ‘arbitrary’](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4638411/21813)):

- Let $n$ be **arbitrary** and suppose that $n\in S$ and that $n\ge a\ldots$
- Let $n$ be an **arbitrary** element of $S,$ and suppose that $n\ge a\ldots$
- Let $n$ be an **arbitrary** element of $S$ such that $n\ge a\ldots$

Also: [How to interpret “let... suppose” in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4053215/21813)

> However, I feel that this doesn't clearly identify that the statement holds for all $n.$

Yes, because at this point you are referring to a *representative* value of $n.$ Then, when wrapping up the proof, you conclude generally that “**for each** $n\ldots$”, by relying on [Universal Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

> Additionally, I'm less inclined to write the phrase “we want to show”.

I think the phrase is reader-friendly!

---

**Addendum**

> @ryan I think the main part I was missing is the “arbitrary element”.

The $n$ in your suggestion is tacitly understood as arbitrary.

---

***user21820*:**

> Contrary to *ryang*'s post, I recommend avoiding "let" for ∀-quantification.

This really is a non-objection: it is the word “**arbitrary**” (tacit or otherwise)—not the word “let”— that signals `∀`.

Answer (score 3):

$\forall x\in D~(x\in A\to x\in B)$ says "For every thing in D, if that thing in A , then that thing is in B."

More briefly, "Everything in D that is in A will be in B"

---

> Take any thing in D.  Suppose it is in A. ...(insert a valid derivation).... So such a thing will be in B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't think it's possible to write "For everything in D, if that thing in A", then a bunch of words, and "Therefore that thing is in B" in a proof.

Comment: .... Why not ? @wsz_fantasy

Comment: I thought people normally use the word "suppose" instead "if" if they want to keep the assumption for many sentences as explained here(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028574/suppose-versus-if).

Answer (score 0):

Your last idea is already very close.

> Suppose $n\geq a$ is such that $n\in S$.  Then ⟨*your proof here*⟩, and thus $n+1\in S$.
>
> Varying $n$ in the above argument, we see that, for any $n\geq a$, the implication ${n\in S}\to{n+1\in S}$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to *ryang*'s post, I recommend [**avoiding "let" for $∀$-quantification**](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550). If you want **actual idiomatic English**, you should not use "let". The idiomatic alternative is:

> Consider/take any n ≥ a that belongs to S. Then ... Thus n+1 also belongs to S.
> Therefore by induction every n ≥ a belongs to S.

The evidence is clear; you can see people telling you *how to interpret "let" in mathematics*, showing that the common manner it is used in mathematics is **not** idiomatic English.

Comment: By the way, be careful of people who are not native English speakers but talk as if they know English better than native speakers.